# Can properties of events be viewed in org-agenda?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have a recurring event that takes place in a specific location:

```
#+Title: My Agenda

* Coffee
** Drink Coffee
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LOCATION: Room 237
   :END:
   <2017-01-01 Sun 09:00-10:00 +1w>
```

My agenda, however, ignores the location of my event:

```
Month-agenda (W52-W05):
Sunday      1 January 2017
  tasks:       9:00am-10:00am Drink Coffee
Monday      2 January 2017 W01
Tuesday     3 January 2017
Wednesday   4 January 2017
Thursday    5 January 2017
Friday      6 January 2017
Saturday    7 January 2017
Sunday      8 January 2017
  tasks:       9:00am-10:00am Drink Coffee
Monday      9 January 2017 W02
Tuesday    10 January 2017
Wednesday  11 January 2017
Thursday   12 January 2017
Friday     13 January 2017
Saturday   14 January 2017
Sunday     15 January 2017
  tasks:       9:00am-10:00am Drink Coffee
Monday     16 January 2017 W03
Tuesday    17 January 2017
Wednesday  18 January 2017
Thursday   19 January 2017
Friday     20 January 2017
Saturday   21 January 2017
Sunday     22 January 2017
  tasks:       9:00am-10:00am Drink Coffee
Monday     23 January 2017 W04
Tuesday    24 January 2017
Wednesday  25 January 2017
Thursday   26 January 2017
Friday     27 January 2017
Saturday   28 January 2017
Sunday     29 January 2017
  tasks:       9:00am-10:00am Drink Coffee
Monday     30 January 2017 W05
Tuesday    31 January 2017
```

Is there a way to view the location of my event in my agenda?

Comment: If you find that `column-view` overlays are not to your liking, have a look at `org-agenda-format-item` -- you can customize said variable and/or you can modify the aforementioned function to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [column view](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Column-View.html) to display any set of properties you like.  Activate column view using `C-c C-x C-c` in the agenda and deactivate it using `q`.  You can control what columns appear by  setting the `COLUMNS` property.  Either at the file level or for a particular subtree (in which case it applies to all its children). You can also set `org-agenda-overriding-columns-format` to select the columns for a custom agenda command.

In this particular example, to show only the headline and the value of the `LOCATION` you can add:

```
 #+COLUMNS: %25ITEM %LOCATION
```

to the top of the file.  Any property can be show and a variety of [formatting](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-attributes.html#Column-attributes) options are available.